# Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands al obtener la versión de angular

Tags: angular-cli

Estaba instalando la cli de angular y sale correctamente instalado pero al momento de verificar la versión me salta este error. ¿Qué puede ser?:

```
Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view
the available commands.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta primero con `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` y luego prueba de nuevo `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez no me funciona tampoco, me olvide decir que estoy en windows con WSL, no se si tenga algo que ver. Aparte que instale node a partir de nvm y no desde su pagina oficial :'( no se si sea por eso también

Comment: Acabo de probarlo en mi cli. El comando que debes ejecutar es `ng version`. No `ng --version` ni `ng -v`.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez nooo bro eres mi héroexD, yo pensaba que tenia que empezar a desmontarlo todo, gracias por el datazo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se describe en el [historial de cambios](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#angularcli) de la versión 14 de `angular-cli`, el comando `ng —-version` fue removido en la nueva versión de angular a favor de `ng version` y  `ng v`.

Por favor, usa a partir de ahora:

```
ng version
```

o bien:

```
ng v
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]