# Angular Error: You need to specify a command before moving on

Tags: cmd, windows10, angular-cli

al tratar de ejecutar calquier comando en el cmd obtengo el error

> Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.

Ya intente lo que sugieren en
[Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands al obtener la versión de angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/539275/error-you-need-to-specify-a-command-before-moving-on-use-help-to-view-the) sin éxito

también ya intenté actualizar la version del angular cli mediante

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

La solucion fue cambiarme a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) donde funciona a la primera, tal vez en nuevas versiones sea el cli sea incompatible con cmd